# How To add Edit And Delete Button to the Dynamically Created Column to each rows

Tags: jquery, datatables, serverside-javascript

I am Having JSON object from which i am creating Dynamic Columns. At 5th position i am having ID which i want to pass to Server. How do i achieve it on click of specific button

```js
var jsonData = data[key[0]];
var column = data[key[1]];

$('#example').DataTable({
  data: jsonData,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 5,
    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
      if (type === 'display') {
        data =
          '<button class="btn-edit" type="button">Edit</button>' +
          '<button class="btn-delete" type="button">Delet</button>';
      }

      return data;
    }
  }],
  columns: column
});
```

Comment: You can provide the ID as a custom HTML5 `data-` attribute to the buttons. Then, listen to the `click` event bubbling up from these buttons and you can then have access to the ID associated with a particular button when it is clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code below.

NOTE: I am assuming you are using array of arrays as your data and ID is the first element (`data[0]`). Otherwise change the code accordingly.

```
// Handle click on "Edit" button
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody .btn-edit', function(){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var data = table.row($row).data();

   // console.log(data);

   alert('Edit ' + data[0]);
});

// Handle click on "Delete" button
$('#example').on('click', 'tbody .btn-delete', function(){
   var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
   var data = table.row($row).data();

   // console.log(data);

   alert('Delete ' + data[0]);
});
```